# Specific sort with Comparer by string contains and alphabetically

Tags: c#, .net, sorting

I want to write Comparer which will return sorted list by string and in alphabet order.
This is my List:

```
AA
AA MN
ADIDAS
ADIDAS MEN
2KC
ISANA MEN
```

Here is my comparer:

```
public class MyComparer : IComparer<string>
{
    int IComparer<string>.Compare(string x, string y)
    {
        if (x == y)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        if (x.Contains(y))
        {
            return -1;
        }
        else
        {
            return 1;
        }
    }
}
```

And this comparer sort my list like that:

```
2KC
ADIDAS MEN
AA MEN
AA
ISANA MEN
ADIDAS
```

It's correct because I want first check "longest" brands (this removes error with finding brand in product), but with this sorting I want sort it alphabetically. So my list should look like

```
2KC
ADIDAS MEN
AA MEN
AA
ADIDAS
ISANA MEN
```

I'm trying with string.Sort(), not work correctly.

Comment: Your comparer has completely unexpected check x.Contains(y). What does it mean, why would you need it like this?

Comment: It's only part of my list. I use OrderBy and one of parameter want Comparer.   Need like this because I want check first brands with optional sufix like `MEN`. Other items in list is `Velvet` and `Bourjois`. With this comparer my result array have first `Velvet` and then `Bourjois`. It's wrong..

Comment: I understand why you want "ADIDAS MEN" to sort before "ADIDAS", but I don't understand why you want it to sort before "AA" and "AA MEN". What, exactly, are your sorting rules?

Comment: It's my mistake. Of course you have right. "ADIDAS" would stay after "ADIDAS MEN" and before "AA...".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two problems. The first is that your comparer violates the rules for `IComparer.Compare`. The rules say that if `A.CompareTo(B)` returns 1, then `B.CompareTo(A)` must return -1. Your comparer doesn't do that. For example, this code:

```
string a = "abc";
string b = "def";
MyComparer comp = new MyComparer();

int rsltab = comp.Compare(a, b);  // returns 1
int rsltba = comp.Compare(b, a);  // returns 1
```

That's plainly wrong.

Whatever else you do in your comparer, you *must* ensure that:

1. If `x.Compare(y)` returns -1, then `y.Compare(x)` returns 1.
2. If `y.Compare(x)` returns -1, then `x.Compare(y)` returns 1.
3. If `x.Compare(y)` returns 0, then `y.Compare(x)` returns 0.

See the Notes to Implementers section of the documentation for [ICompareble.CompareTo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/43hc6wht(v=vs.110).aspx) for more information about the rules for comparisons. I'm kind of surprised that this information isn't repeated in the documentation for `IComparer<T>`.

The other problem is that I don't think you really want to test to see if `x` *contains* `y`. Maybe you want to check to see if `x` *starts with* `y`. That is:

```
if (x.StartsWith(y)) return 1;
```

But that, too, could give you some strange results. For example, what if one company's name is just a prefix of the first word in another's? For example:

```
Art
Artificial Flavor Company
```

Do you really want Artificial Flavor Company to sort before Art, even though the companies aren't related?

I suspect that what you really want is to parse the string and see if the first word of the longer string is equal to the shorter string. So given "ADIDAS" and "ADIDAS MEN", you would parse the longer string to get the first word, and compare that against the shorter string. That's not a perfect solution, but it will be much more effective than what you currently have.

Comment: Thank you for help and understanding me how it works :) Yes I want first check longer brand and then shorter. It's removes errors with classify brand to product. But as i said there is more brands and for example words where no contains (it's bad) are sorted randomly. Word with `B` in first char is farther than another word for `V`